# How to create a nested dictionaries structure in ios?

Tags: ios, iphone, ios5

I get the response from service like one user contain number of episodes under number of seasons.
ex:

- A user contain 10 seasons under 1 season 10 episodes,2 season 15,3rd
  9...
- B user contain 14 seasons under 1 season 6 episodes,2 season 20,3rd
  5...
- c user contain 3 seasons under 1 season 4 episodes,2 season 10,3rd 8

how will i show list of episodes in particular season.resopnse coming

```
"Episodes":{
    "1": {
        "Season": "3",
        "Episode": "10",

    },
    "2": {
        "Season": "1",
        "Episode": "2",

    },
.
.
  "78":{
    "Season": "10",
    "Episode": "20",

  }
```

Comment: what is the key here, 1, 2, 3, .....78. please explain

Comment: I can't see how the text in your question corresponds to your dictionary log code. You need to explain differently.

Answer (score 0):

You just use for in loop through the whole thing.

Create a dictionary for every season there is. Every episode you loop through, insert the episode for key

```
[season1 setObject:[Episodes objectForKey:index] forKey: [[Episodes objectForKey:index] objectForKey:Episode]
```

So you will then have a dictionary for every season, and every dictionary will have the episodes that the user currently has, sorted.